# Christmas Cactus leaf discoloration

Tags: plant-health, holiday-cactus

I received this Christmas Cactus as a cutting from a larger plant about a year ago. It has been growing and doing well over that time. In the past month I have noticed some of the end leaves begin to turn a reddish color.

**Is this normal?**

[image: far]
[image: close]

**UPDATE** 04/05/2016

The plant was root bound in the pot. I have transferred it to a larger pot and added new soil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This reddening is usually the response of some form of 'shock'.

It could possibly be one of two things in my understanding of this plant.

1. Too much sun is reaching the leaves affected.
2. Or it isn't getting enough nutrients.

Check that it hasn't become too root bound in its current pot.

[This](http://www.garden.org/searchqa/index.php?q=show&id=105701&ps=8&keyword=cactus) gives a little more detail.

Comment: Thanks! I the plant was root bound. I have transferred it to a larger pot and given it new soil.

Comment: Good, just rooted a couple of branches from my mother's plant over the last couple of weeks